# Error while updating Jenkins job config using Rest API

Tags: java, jenkins, config, jenkins-api

I am trying to change the configuration of a job using Jenkins' rest API using my java code, but it is not able to connect to Jenkins url.

Please, suggest me the changes so that I can update my job without restarting the Jenkins. I am using Jenkins 2.19.4. 
Is there any jenkins setting, which is blocking me to connect to jenkins config.xml or java code is having some problem?

```
try
    {
        String fileDir = "D:\\"; // upload directory
          String fileName = "config.xml";
          URL url = new URL("http://myjenkins/job/test/config.xml"); // Jenkins URL localhost:8080, job named 'test'

          String user = "username"; // username
          String pass = "password"; // password or API token
          String authStr = user +":"+  pass;
          String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(authStr.getBytes("utf-8"));

          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
          connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setUseCaches(false);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

          try
          {

              String filePath = "D:\\config.xml";
              FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
              FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(filePath));
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                String sCurrentLine;
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine = br.readLine());
              OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    //System.out.println("not going inside!!!!");
                    writer.write(sCurrentLine);
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                }
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(responseCode);                
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am getting 403 http response with java.io exception

Comment: 403 suggests the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it...check if the user/pwd are correct and passed with expected encoding

Comment: user name and password both are correct.

Comment: @KrutiVyas I am still not able to connect to Jenkins. Using code as above and also CSRF is not abled. What to do to create a jenkin job.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for 403 response is CSRF security. Either disable that option from the jenkins. Or set Crumb for each http request.